# Limit representation of delta function as discrete Gaussian sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, dirac-delta

There is a representation of the delta function as the limit:

$$ \delta(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \left [ \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \exp \left (- \frac{x^2}{2 \epsilon} \right ) \right ]^{-1} \exp \left (- \frac{x^2}{2 \epsilon} \right ) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\epsilon}} \exp \left (- \frac{x^2}{2 \epsilon} \right ) $$

Is the following also a valid "discrete" representation?

$$ \delta(n) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \left [ \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \exp \left (- \frac{n^2}{2 \epsilon} \right ) \right ]^{-1} \exp \left (- \frac{n^2}{2 \epsilon} \right ) $$

Comment: This is doubtful. Consider that the integral and the sum are not asymptotically equivalent when $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ (they are when $\epsilon \to \infty$). Do you assign some special meaning to $\delta(n)$, or do you want an exact equivalent of the first formula and $n$ is just a dummy variable in the sum?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean what I think you mean, then the answer is yes. In contrast to the continuous case, here the functions converge to a function, namely $\delta(n)=\delta_{n0}$ (the Kronecker symbol). If this is the function that you wanted to "represent", then you did. I'd expect the usefulness of such a "representation" to be more limited than in the continuous case, where a *distribution* is represented by a sequence of functions.

Comment: Can I expand the question with some new thoughts? Would it even need the normalization factor in the denominator - in the limit of small epsilon, the normalization is 1 at zero and 0 everywhere else?

Comment: @Kurt: True, but then $\delta_\epsilon(n)$ won't be normalized for $\epsilon\ne0$. Whether that's a problem depends on what you want to use this for.